# Wildfly Docker container Connection refused when connect to postgres at port 5432

Tags: postgresql, docker, deployment, port, wildfly

I'm running a project which is deploy a war file to Wildfly server with Docker.
I planned to use Wildfly 27.0.1.Final and Postgres 9.4.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    database:
        image: postgres:9.4
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        networks:
            - resolute
     wildfly:
        depends_on:
            - database
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "9990:9990"
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=database
            - DB_NAME=postgres
            - DB_USER=postgres
            - DB_PASS=123456
        networks:
            - resolute
        command: /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0

networks:
    resolute:
        name: resolute
```

And my Dockerfile to build Wildfly container:

```
FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:27.0.1.Final-jdk17

COPY ./module.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main
COPY ./eclipselink-4.0.0.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main
COPY ./standalone-full.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration

ADD ./postgresql-42.6.0.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
ADD ./my-war-file.war .

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh -u 'admin' -p 'admin'
```

My datasoure in standalone-full.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>
        jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/postgres
    </connection-url>
    <driver-class>
        org.postgresql.Driver
    </driver-class>
    <datasource-class>
        org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    </datasource-class>
    <driver>
        postgresql-42.6.0.jar
    </driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>
            postgres
        </user-name>
        <password>
            123456
        </password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker" />
        <background-validation>
            true
        </background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter" />
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

Then I run `docker-compose up --build` to build.

Containers start is fine, postgres42.6.0 was deployed successfully.

Then I go into wildfly container has just been created to copy my war file to `/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/`

The container continues running to deploy my war file but I've got this error.

```
2023-08-22 14:30:30 07:30:30,507 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "my-war-file.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
2023-08-22 14:30:30     "jboss.deployment.unit.\"my-war-file.war\".component.DataLoader.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: jakarta.ejb.EJBException: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.0.v202210051929): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
2023-08-22 14:30:30 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PostgresDS
2023-08-22 14:30:30 Error Code: 0
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.0.v202210051929): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
2023-08-22 14:30:30 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PostgresDS
2023-08-22 14:30:30 Error Code: 0
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.0.v202210051929): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
2023-08-22 14:30:30 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PostgresDS
2023-08-22 14:30:30 Error Code: 0
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PostgresDS
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PostgresDS
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: jakarta.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused",
2023-08-22 14:30:30     "jboss.deployment.unit.\"my-war-file.war\".component.AddrSearcherStartUp.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: jakarta.ejb.EJBException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:9899/addr_searcher?wsdl. It failed with: 
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Got Connection refused while opening stream from http://localhost:9899/addr_searcher?wsdl.
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:9899/addr_searcher?wsdl. It failed with: 
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Got Connection refused while opening stream from http://localhost:9899/addr_searcher?wsdl.
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Got Connection refused while opening stream from http://localhost:9899/addr_searcher?wsdl
2023-08-22 14:30:30     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"
2023-08-22 14:30:30 }}
```

How should I fix this error ? Many thanks in advance.